# Looping through group and add sum formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have Structure with multiple group and sub groups, where sub groups level can go more than 10. Similar to this (this is level 4).

[image]

Now I want to sum or do some calculation in each group and at the end I want the total in group 1.

I want the sum similar to the one in shown image, Each group will be added then Final value will be calculated. The no of rows or groups are variable for me, So I need to add the formula through VBA, After I have the input (Rows and groups).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here's a Pro Tip: Record a Macro, do your calculations, stop macro, check code in the module in the VB Editor (Alt+F11)

Comment: You didn't ask a question: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). And it is very unclear what you have tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: I'd advise to step back and start looking at pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted...

```
    'Update assembly levels
            For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
                Call UpdateAssemblyLevel(RowCount, i)
            Next i

    Sub UpdateAssemblyLevel(RCount As Integer, CurrentLevel As Integer)

    'Adding Formulae for assembly levels

    Dim MassRange As Range
    Dim AssemblyMass As Integer
    Dim MR As Range           
    Set MassRange = Nothing        
    AssemblyMass = 0

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = RCount To 2 Step -1

            If Cells(i, 1).Value = CurrentLevel Then        
                Set MR = Cells(i, 12)
                MsgBox (MR.Value)
                    If Not MassRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set MassRange = Union(MassRange, MR)
                    Else
                        Set MassRange = MR
                    End If

            ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = CurrentLevel - 1 Then
                    'Add the Sum here
                    If MassRange Is Nothing Then
                        'Do Nothing
                    Else       
                        Cells(i, 12).Formula = "=SUM(" & MassRange.Address & ")" 'This gives me wrong value then desired output                            
                        Set MassRange = Nothing
                    End If

                AssemblyMass = 0

            Else
                'Do nothing
            End If        

        Next i

    End Sub
```